# Why do I get a build warning "button is assigned but its value is never used" in the Xamarin.Forms hello world example?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm following the hello xamarin quickstart project https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/ for Xamarin.Forms and I'm getting a warning `The private field Phoneword.MainPage.translateButon is assigned but its value is never used`  in the generated code files

```
/Demo/Phoneword/obj/Debug/Phoneword.MainPage.xaml.g.cs(46,46): Warning CS0414: The private field `Phoneword.MainPage.translateButon' is assigned but its value is never used (CS0414) (Phoneword)
```

Here's the XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="XamDemo.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="20, 40, 20, 20" Android="20, 20, 20, 20" WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="15">
            <Label Text="Enter a Phoneword:" />
            <Entry x:Name="phoneNumberText" Text="1-855-XAMARIN" />
            <Button x:Name="translateButon" Text="Translate" Clicked="OnTranslate" />
            <Button x:Name="callButton" Text="Call" IsEnabled="false" Clicked="OnCall" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Why am I getting that warning?  The project seems to work fine and the translate button does call a method so it is being used.  I don't get the same warning for callButton which seems like it was declared in the same way.  What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `translateButon` field is generated in the `Phoneword.MainPage.xaml.g.cs` file because of the `x:Name="translateButon"` attribute.

This attribute gives you access to the `Button` element if you wanted to do anything with it in the `MainPage.cs` code file.

But all you need to do is done in the Xaml, namely what action should happen on click. So the warning will disappear if you remove the `x:Name="translateButon"` attribute.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I see now that it didn't have the same warning for the call button because that object was referenced in the code behind.